# How to modify contents in a file?

Tags: c, logic

I am a complete beginner of C. My problem is to modify a content in a file.

I am writing two files and then merge the contents of the two files in a another file. This another file is the one I need to modify.

what to modify?

The myfile1.txt values are 199112345671273 and the myfile2.txt values are 24AUS2024MED712.

The merging file (myfile3.txt) has 19911234567127324AUS2024MED712

The thing that I need to modify is the values of myfile2.txt. I want to hide its values in asterisk so when reading myfile3.txt,I get the following

199112345671273****************

my logic is messed up. I just want to stores both values of myfile1 and myfile2. then display myfile3 in condition that myfile2 has to be hidden in asterisk when reading.

My write.c program - write data in two files

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 100

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    char registration[MAX_SIZE], location[MAX_SIZE], faculty[MAX_SIZE];
    int birthOfYear, birthOfMonth, birthOfDate, layerArch1, layerArch2, levelOfStudy, graduatingYear;

    FILE *fptr, *anotherfptr;
    fptr = fopen("myfile01.txt","w");
    anotherfptr = fopen("myfile02.txt", "w");
    if(fptr == NULL) {
            printf("Error!");   
            exit(1);             
    }

    printf("Enter a registration number (XXXXXX): ");
    scanf("%s", registration); //read as a string

    printf("Enter location (location as in currency, AUS CND SIN: ");
    scanf("%s", location); //read as a string

    printf("Enter faculty (ENG BUS SCI MED): ");
    scanf("%s", faculty); //read as a string

    printf("Enter birth of year (19XX 200X): ");
    scanf("%d", &birthOfYear);

    printf("Enter birth of month (XX): ");
    scanf("%d", &birthOfMonth);

    printf("Enter birth of date (XX): ");
    scanf("%d", &birthOfDate);

    printf("Enter level of study (1 -first, 2- second, 3- third, 4-fourth, 5 - other): ");
    scanf("%d", &levelOfStudy);

    printf("Enter graduating year (XXXX): ");
    scanf("%d",&graduatingYear);

    printf("Enter layer of Architecture 1 (0-sensing, 1-network, 2-smart(hidden), 3-devices): ");
    scanf("%d",&layerArch1);

    printf("Enter layer of Architecture 2 (0-sensing, 1-network, 2-smart(hidden), 3-devices): ");
    scanf("%d",&layerArch2);

    fprintf(fptr,"%d%s%d%d%d", birthOfYear, registration, birthOfMonth, birthOfDate, layerArch1); //writing into file with some formatting 
    fclose(fptr);

    fprintf(anotherfptr,"%d%d%s%d%s%d%d", layerArch2, levelOfStudy, location, graduatingYear, faculty, birthOfDate, birthOfMonth); 
    //writing into file with some formatting

    fclose(anotherfptr);

    return 0;
  }
```

my merge.c program - to merge two files

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   FILE *fs1, *fs2, *ft;

   char ch, file1[200], file2[200], file3[200];

   printf("Enter name of first file\n");
   gets(file1);

   printf("Enter name of second file\n");
   gets(file2);

   printf("Enter name of file which will store contents of the two files\n");
   gets(file3);

   fs1 = fopen(file1, "r");
   fs2 = fopen(file2, "r");

   if(fs1 == NULL || fs2 == NULL)
   {
      perror("Error ");
      printf("Press any key to exit...\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   ft = fopen(file3, "w"); // Opening in write mode

   if(ft == NULL)
   {
      perror("Error ");
      printf("Press any key to exit...\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   while((ch = fgetc(fs1)) != EOF)
      fputc(ch,ft);

   while((ch = fgetc(fs2)) != EOF)
      fputc(ch,ft);

   printf("The two files were merged into %s file successfully.\n", file3);

   fclose(fs1);
   fclose(fs2);
   fclose(ft);

   return 0;
}
```

my read.c - to read files

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char c[1000];
    FILE *fptr, anotherfptr;

    if ((fptr = fopen("myfile1.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error! opening file");
        exit(1);         
    }

    // reads text until newline 
    fscanf(fptr,"%[^\n]", c);
    printf("Data from the file:\n%s", c);
    fclose(fptr);

    if ((fptr = fopen("myfile2.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error! opening file");
        exit(1);         
    }

    // reads text until newline 
    fscanf(anotherfptr,"%[^\n]", c);
    printf("Data from the file:\n%s", c);
    fclose(anotherfptr);
    return 0;
}
```

My issue is my logic on how to solve this simple program. I am literally stuck.

Any help/clarification would be much appreciated.

Comment: current location, country.

Comment: One problem of course is that `%s` reads space-delimited stuff and you're printing the stuff without any intervening spaces...

Comment: And how do you intend to tell 1 Dec  apart from 21 Jan in the birth date...

Comment: Contents replaced by asterisks? But you *are* aware that, once this happened, you *cannot* recover original string from?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I am here to figure out what mistakes I am doing.

Comment: @Aconcagua I would like to hide some values using asterisk.

Comment: Please write in detail what you get instead of the expected.

Comment: Minor linguistic matter: `birth of year` – funny, a new year is born... You meant 'year of birth'.

Comment: Pretty strange. What's the purpose of third file? What would you need it for? Logfiles, hiding away passwords? But you shouldn't reveal length of passwords either, for security purposes. To me looks pretty much like an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Aconcagua I did it on purpose though. I think this is part of my assignment. would you think showing the assignment question here will do any better?

Comment: Whichever teacher taught you about `gets()`, fire him. Preferably through a cannon.

Comment: At a first step, a short description of what you actually try to solve with these three files might suffice. At very least, try not to post parts of the assignment that obviously are unrelated to the problem...

Comment: When talking about `gets` (actually, that even got removed from C standard with C11 – a thing that really rarely happens with C...): `scanf("%s")` without a length guard isn't any safer either... So what are the safe ways to do? Several options, [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) allows you to specify maximum length to read, and `scanf("%77s")` specifies maximum length as well.

Comment: Be aware that the meaning of maximum differs in both variants: `fgets` accepts maximum buffer size (so *includes* space for the terminating null character), `scanf` specifies maximum number of characters to read (so you need to *leave* space for the terminating null character): `char buffer[128]; fgets(buffer, 128, stdin); scanf("%127s", buffer);`

Comment: @Aconcagua apologize for the late reply. I'll try to modify and what sees fit in my code. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you need to create a program which should know the content/size of 'myfile1.txt' or 'myfile2.txt' so as to show * for the second content while reading 'myfile3.txt'.

I prefer not to create separate c programs for each task but to use it as a function in one single program.

Coming to the logic : **Masking is what you are searching for.** Basically it is used as a password masking. ( You might have seen * while typing password in any sites. ). In your case you want to display a content as * without actually changing the content in file.

Get an idea of how masking is done for password in the below document :

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-in-place-of-characters-for-reading-passwords-in-c/

Comment: this is correct. but not sure how to implement it :/

Comment: the logic can be to store the number of bytes 'myfile1.txt' contains. And then start reading 'myfile3.txt' and print the content until those number of bytes and after that print asterisk for rest of the content.
If you are reading file till next line as in read.c then you can store the value in some other variable and then apply above logic on that variable.

Comment: Thank you for the instructions. I'd like to update you about my final code. It would be nice if you could check it later.

Comment: @newguyinstuckoverflow If it *really* is about passwords: ***DON'T*** reveal their length! That excludes a large number of passwords an attacker would have to check, thus reduces security... If you want to get even better: Don't store passwords as clear text. Only store a [hash value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) (which you would have to re-calculate on user input to verify logins).

Comment: @Aconcagua... I agree with your point... But it doesn't seem to be related to password. This is a simple text which here we are trying to mask... but for the reference we can check how password mapping is done. Also there is no user input.

Comment: @ShivendraPratapKushwaha OK then. To be honest, the entire task doesn't appear meaningful to me – rather looks as if just playing around with file IO...

Comment: @ShivendraPratapKushwaha what I am going to do is to input user value and store it in two files. Then, these two files will be merged. Once the new file is created, your algorithms/logic is the one that I'm going to implement

Comment: @Aconcagua I think what Shivendra suggested is the one I am looking for here. I am conflicted to find the alogirthms to masks some values stored in a file. Whether this task does not appear meaningful, but thank you for answering and your time.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have tried all possible way out. Please check the solution below :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
char c1[1000];
char c3[1000];
FILE *fptr, *anotherfptr;

if ((fptr = fopen("myfile1.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
    printf("Error! opening file");
    exit(1);
}

// reads text until newline
fscanf(fptr,"%[^\n]", c1);
printf("Data from the file myfile1.txt :%s\n", c1);
fclose(fptr);

//calculate the length of string c1
int lengthc1=strlen(c1);
printf("Length of string c1 is : %d\n", lengthc1);

if ((anotherfptr = fopen("myfile3.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
    printf("Error! opening file");
    exit(1);
}

// reads text until newline
fscanf(anotherfptr,"%[^\n]", c3);
printf("Data from the file myfile3.txt :%s\n", c3);
fclose(anotherfptr);

//to show data of myfile2.txt in astrisk
int lengthc3=strlen(c3);
printf("Final data is ");
for ( int i=0 ; i<=lengthc3 ; i++)
{
    if (i < lengthc1)
    {
            printf("%c", c3[i]);
    }
    else
    {
            printf("*");
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you for this and apologize for the very late reply as I am very busy with coursework. I am currently working on the coding. But the source code is merely a trial/error (simple coding) because I am going to redo it again so that the program can be run in real time. I have to allocate memory as well. Anyway, I am not very novice to programming as I have been using C for system programming and Java for university. My problem is I need to improve my logic skills at some point.

Comment: @newguyinstuckoverflow Hope the above code helps you with the logic you were stuck. You can still do a lot of improvement.